# How do I Wrap Text in PySimpleGUI Table Headings

Tags: python, pandas, word-wrap, pysimplegui

I have created a PySimpeGUI table using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import PySimpleGUI as sg

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Data/dummydata.csv')
data = df.values.tolist()
headings = df.columns.tolist()

def main():
    layout = [sg.Table(values=data, headings=headings, auto_size_columns=True,
                        display_row_numbers=False, num_rows = len(data), enable_events=True,
                        justification='left', key='_TABLE_', vertical_scroll_only = False)],
    window = sg.Window('Dummy Name', auto_size_text=True, auto_size_buttons=True,
                       grab_anywhere=False, resizable=True,
                       layout=layout, finalize=True)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == "Exit" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
    window.close()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get the following table:

[image: Table 1]

As you can see, the length of the column headers is increasing the width of some of the columns, even though the relevant data does not need the columns to be wide. Can someone tell me how to wrap the text in the column headings in PySimpleGUI so I can reduce the size of these columns? I tried turning off auto_size_columns but then the column headings just get cut off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special requirement here, so tkinter code for it.

Example Code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

headings = ['A1', 'B1\nB2', 'C1\nC2\nC3']
data = [[1,2,3], [2,4,6], [3,6,9]]

layout = [
    [sg.Table(values=data, headings=headings, num_rows=10, col_widths=[4, 4, 4],
        cols_justification='ccc', auto_size_columns=False, key='-TABLE-')],
]
location = sg.Window.get_screen_size()
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True, location=location)

# Set 3-line heading height
table = window['-TABLE-']
table.widget.heading('#0', text='\n\n')                                # 3 lines

# Update the GUI for the Table
style_name = table.table_ttk_style_name + '.Heading'
style = table.ttk_style
foreground = style.configure(style_name)['foreground']
style.configure(style_name, foreground=foreground)

# Relocate window to center of the screen
window.refresh()
window.move_to_center()

window.read(close=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I'm reading this correctly, essentially what you are doing is splitting the columns by hand using \n and then using Tkinter to read the \n as text splits, then manually setting a 3 column height? Plus some code to get screen size and center it, which is something I wanted to do but also wasn't quite sure hot to yet. It may take me a bit to figure out how to implement this to my code, but I think this solves my question so I'm going to mark this as answered.

Comment: Updated for more comment in code.